# link_to many tags instead of a single string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a list of user notifications. When the current user clicks an `<li>` tag, which contains the entire notification content, they should be redirected to the mentioned post or user etc.

Here is what I am trying right now and can't seem to get it to work.

```
<%= link_to activity.activable do %>
  <span><%= link_to(image_tag(activity.actor.avatar.url(:thumb)), user_path(activity.actor.username)) %></span>
  <span class="us-rt-sg">
    <%= link_to activity.actor.name, user_path(activity.actor.username), class: "us-rt-usnm" %>
    <%= activity.action %> on
    <%= link_to personalize_owner(activity, recepient), user_path(activity.activable.user.username) %>
    <%= link_to 'Post', activity.activable %>
    <br>
    <span class="us-rt-sg-date"><%= time_ago_in_words(activity.created_at) %></span>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Once I get this to work, I will remove the line `<%= link_to 'Post', activity.activable %>`, because the entire `<li>` will be a link when clicked.

---

I also tried this on my activities main view page.

```
<li class="activity">
  <%= link_to activity.activable do %>
    <%= render "activities/#{activity.action}", activity: activity, recepient: recepient %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

---

Can someone show me what I need to do? Because so far everyhing I've done has not worked.

Comment: Hiya - firstly it'd help us if you could explain * what you observe happening * and what you you expect to see happening instead (right now you have variation on "it just doesn't work" which doesn't help us narrow down exactly what the problem might be :) ). Also - have you tried to make a plain-html mockup of what you'd like an example to be like... and seen if it works at all? My first guess (without the info above) is that you have links inside of links, and html might just not do that very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapping `link_to` and the internal links are going to give you a headache. You have to decide what's most important in the element.

On the face of it, where you have a notification that should be clickable and link to the specified activity, you should remove the internal links and just link the whole content to the activity. Once they arrive at the activity, then you can include links to author, owner, and so on without worrying about a wrapping link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are attempting to nest anchor links, which is against the W3C standard.  You won't be able to use the link_to tag from within a link to block.  You can, however, make the on Click event handler fire by assigning an id and using the data attributes to store the destination

```
<li class="clickable" data-destination="<%=activity.activable%>"
  <%= link_to activity.actor.name, user_path(activity.actor.username), class: "us-rt-usnm" %>
   xxxxxx
</li>

#JQuery example
$('.clickable").on('click', function () {window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-destination') });
```